# Generate random number in Unity without class ambiguity

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem in Unity (C#) where I would like to create a random number. I wanted to use `System.Random` (reference: using `System`) but Unity complains that it's ambiguous to their own `UnityEngine.Random`. I can not specify the reference (using `System.Random`) as `random` is not a namespace. How do I specify that I want to use the system random and not the Unity one?

Comment: It seems to me that the title of the question doesn't really reflect the question. The easiest way to do what the tile says is simply use Unity's RNG, which may be generally good advice anyway. Of course if you're not using anything from the UnityEngine namespace (unlikely) you could just omit that using statement.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could specify the namespace explicitly:

```
System.Random random = new System.Random(seed);
random.Next();
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use a [using alias directive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) to give System.Random a new name as well:

```
using Rng = System.Random;
```

Comment: `using Random = System.Random;` is fine too

Comment: `using LiterallyAnyOldString = System.Random;` is also fine, you can use anything you want, the same rules apply as for variables

Comment: @MindSwipe I think trollingchar's point was that `Random` is fine and unambiguous, even in contexts where `UnityEngine.Random` is available.